# Unable to remove child

Tags: javascript, jquery, removechild

I am trying to remove a child element based on its index from its parent container. I have tried just about everything i can think of to get it to work and with no results. I feel like removing a child from its parent on a click event should be an easy task.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is my codepen.io link:http://codepen.io/theller5567/pen/wWvJjv?editors=1010
the code below is under CompareBasket.prototype.removeItem function

```
var d = this.el;
var preview = $('[data-idx = "' + items.indexOf(item) + '"]')[0];
console.log(preview);
this.el.removeChild(preview);
```

this.el = $('.compare-basket');

to add an item to the compare basket click on the plus icon at the top right of product. to remove item click on the small icon at top of page in compare-basket div.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery.

Comment: try `$('[data-idx = "' + items.indexOf(item) + '"]').remove()`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! Little confused on why var preview = this.el.querySelector('[data-idx = "' + items.indexOf(item) + '"]');
  this.el.removeChild(preview); doesn't work. any thoughts?

Comment: Because this `this.el` is a jQuery object not native dom element and jQuery doesn't have method `removeChild()`. You should be seeing console errors to help guide you with clues...use your browser dev tools...they are there for troubleshooting!

Comment: Console errors didn't help very well with figuring out my problem. I use console logs excessively for debugging purposes. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

@MajediSabuj solved the problem: try $('[data-idx = "' + items.indexOf(item) + '"]').remove();

Still not sure why the original code i had did not work:

```
var preview = this.el.querySelector('[data-idx = "' + items.indexOf(item) + '"]'); this.el.removeChild(preview);
```

But it works:)

Comment: Really making a big mistake mixing jquery and native methods. Use one or the other. Maintaining your code later will be a whole lot easier when consistent conventions are used. Otherwise opening door for lots of head scratching and wasted time later. In fact that confusion is already apparent in the question itself